# Pre-initialized Bitbucket repository. Visibility on past commits

Tags: git, repository, commit, bitbucket

I'm working on a private Bitbucket repository and I would like to make it public after removing some private files. My question is: can I prevent users to revert past commits of such repository? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, the simplest thing to do would be to set-up a new repo and commit the stable public safe code.

Comment: As I suspected. Thank you for the answer. I've already created a new empty repository.